# Track C++ application with google analytics

Tags: c++, google-analytics

Is a possibility to track my C++ application usage using google analytics?

Comment: Having offline applications report usage statistics is all kinds of shady. Why not just track downloads?

Comment: @meagar: well, it's OK in principle as long as the tickybox at install is clear enough. For instance, audioscrobbler tracks usage of offline apps, that's why users want it! But it's normal to anonymize usage data when that data is for the benefit of the app author, and if you track usage by hitting pages that have analytics on them, then Google is receiving personally identifiable information (IP addresses). Even if it doesn't store them or pass them on to you, it's outside your control to guarantee, so it might be a tiny bit shady for that reason.

Comment: @Steve This is why I block outbound connections to google and run [ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9609/)

Comment: @meagar: Heh - "Ghostery also includes the optional, opt-in feature called GhostRank, which sends Ghostery servers anonymous information about the trackers you encounter and where you encounter them", which is kind of what I'm talking about. Does it play nicely with NoScript?

Comment: @Steve Seems to, haven't had any issues with it

Comment: Using Google Analytics to track Desktop apps has a few perks that can easily come back and bite you. This blog post outlines what you should know: http://blog.trackerbird.com/content/tracking-desktop-applications-with-google-analytics-what-you-should-know/

   Disclaimer: I am the author.

Comment: "Having offline applications report usage statistics is all kinds of shady"
These days, probably just about all mobile apps have analytics :) Though still a lack of options on desktop C++ apps.

Answer (score 9):

to track application usage with google analytics is necessary to generate http request to this url:
*

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?
        utmwv=3&
        utmn=<random number>&
        utme=&
        utmcs=ISO-8859-1&
        utmsr=1280x1024&
        utmsc=24-bit&
        utmul=en-us&
        utmje=1&
        utmfl=-&
        utmhn=<www.stopka.us>&
        utmhid=2112093191&
        utmr=-&
        utmp=/login.php?user=12&
        utmac=UA-XXXXX-1&
        utmcc=__utma%3D1.<unique id>.<time (in sec's since Jan 1, 1970) of first
visit).<time of last visit>.<time of current visit>.<visit count>%3B
%2B
        __utmz%3D1.1203103189.1.1.utmcsr%3D<source>%7Cutmccn%3D<campaign>
%7Cutmcmd%3D<medium>%3B
```

*
all parameters is possible to fill with it's user env. values. 
This way is not convenient enough.
So, I create my own library. I call it UsageAnalytics and distribute it as open source project at: http://code.google.com/p/usageanalytics/

thanks for all for participation, thanks for me for the library.

btw. cause code.google.com outdated, I've moved that stuff to

https://github.com/vyemialyanchyk/usageanalytics

Comment: Google now provides an API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Answer (score 3):

By now you may have already solved your need, but for what it's worth, my firm has also released a C library supporting Google's Universal Analytics Measurement Protocol.

https://github.com/analytics-pros/universal-analytics-c

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Google has a library for accessing Analytics API from C++, it's in "alpha", but it looks like what you want... https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/cpp/apis/analytics/v2.4

Comment: The Google APIs C++ Client Library is no longer available. Thank you for your interest.  --Google Developers

Answer (score 2):

The best library I found for tracking analytics with c++ is this unofficial one on github: https://github.com/HSAnet/qt-google-analytics

Note however that it has Qt as a dependency...

Comment: That worked well for me though needed some changes to get it working with Visual Studio's Qt plugin. Many thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track C++ Android or iOS apps you could use Google's Firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/cpp/start

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but nowadays more and more developers are starting to use usage analytics for their software.
"SoftMeter", a library I created myself, is my solution to this need. 
It has a native C and C++ interface.
https://www.starmessagesoftware.com/softmeter/sdk-api