# What is the best way to integrate Google Analytics into a C++ OpenFrameworks desktop project?

Tags: c++, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, openframeworks

I'm currently building an OpenFrameworks project and need to use Google Analytics to track user interactions. I have yet to find any existing C++ libraries for doing so, and am considering writing my own. Is the API open enough to allow a custom library to be created? If one doesn't exist, any ideas on where to begin coding my own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track C++ application with google analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338557/track-c-application-with-google-analytics)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and easy to extend openframeworks!

You can look [here](http://ofxaddons.com/) if there is an addon which fits your need. Maybe ofxCurl or ofxHttpUtils are the right ones to create an request like the one mentioned in the comment by yahelc.

If you don't find a solution there, you can look [here](http://ofxaddons.com/howto) to find first informations about creating addons for openFrameworks. If you have any further questions, please ask in the official openframeworks forums which you can find [here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/).

Comment: I ended up using ofxHttpUtils to create a custom analytics add-on. GA really doesn't cater to desktop apps (probably for good reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll have to build your own solution... I'd use ofxHttpUtils to ping Google's [Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/). You should also consider wrapping your work as an OF addon and sharing in openframewors.cc

Answer (score 0):

I've built an OpenFrameworks add-on to do just that:

http://github.com/armadillu/ofxGoogleAnalytics